# Confused about pop_back(), C++

Tags: c++

I am trying to understand the behavior of `vector::pop_back()`. So I have following code snippet:

```
vector<int> test;
test.push_back(1);
test.pop_back();
cout << test.front() << endl;
```

Maybe it is right but it surprises me that it prints out 1. So I am confused. Is `pop_back()` only able to remove the element has `index > 0` ?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you're not convinced the vector's empty (it is), you can always test using `cout << test.size() << endl;`

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You are invoking undefined behaviour by calling `front` on an empty vector. That's like indexing out of the bounds of an array. Anything could happen, including returning `1`.

Answer (score 10):

`pop_back` here leaves the vector empty. Accessing an empty vector's `front()` is *undefined behavior*. This means that anything can happen - there's no predicting what. It could crash, it could return 1, it could return 42, it could print "Hello, world!", it could erase your hard drive, or it could [summon demons through your nasal passages](http://catb.org/jargon/html/N/nasal-demons.html). Any of these are acceptable actions, as far as C++ is concerned - here it *just happened* to end up returning `1`. Don't rely on it.